# I need a regex expression that will replace all spaces inside square brackets with underscores in Visual Studio Project

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I am able to write a regex expression to find all underscores in a VS SQL Project.

`\[[a-z]+\s[a-z]+\]` (looks inside a string that starts and ends with `[]`).

I need a regex replace expression in VS so I can replace in files so it will replace all spaces with underscores _ only inside of `[]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Any example test case? You say you tried `\[[a-z]+\s[a-z]+]`, right? But you have not even captured the letters and the brackets. Also, does that mean you do not want to touch spaces that are immediately after `[` and before `]`? Is it Visual Studio, or Visual Studio Code?

Comment: For example I have a column name in a table create script [Skip a Payment] [decimal](18,2) I would like this to be [Skip_A_Payment] [decimal](18,2) Thank you!

Comment: Is it Visual Studio or VS Code? And you want to titlecase the words?

Comment: It is SQL Create table scripts inside a VS 2019 SQL Server Project. I would like to keep whatever casing the word is. Thank you!

Comment: Try replacing `(?<=\[[^][]*)\b\s+\b(?=[^][]*])` with `_`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/RkBbgi/1).

Comment: Oh, except some start with #, example [# Delq 120 Days] this ends up being [# Delq_120_Days]

Comment: Cool, so use `(?<=\[[^][]*)\s+(?=[^][]*])`, see my answer below, especially the note at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?<=\[[^][]*)\s+(?=[^][]*])
```

Replace with `_`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RkBbgi/2).

*Details*:

- `(?<=\[[^][]*)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `[` and then zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=[^][]*])` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]` char.

**NOTE**: If the spaces right after `[` and right before `]` and between non-word chars must not be replaced, add word boundaries, `\b`: `(?<=\[[^][]*)\b\s+\b(?=[^][]*])`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RkBbgi/1).

Comment: Shouldn't you also replace trailing spaces? I only ask because you seemed to write a test for it and didn't match them

Comment: @Blindy Exactly, they must not be matched. I added a NOTE.

Comment: The above works great, except for two exceptions, when there is a # at the beginning (i.e. [# My Column Name] comes out as [# My_Column_Name] and if there is a "(", i.e. [My Column (Name)] becomes [My_Column (Name)]